# How do I undo mix phoenix.gen.html?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

`mix phoenix.gen.html` generates a bunch of files.  How do I do undo this generation?  or do i have to do it by hand?

Comment: Code says no - https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/mix/tasks/phoenix.gen.html.ex

Comment: Just an idea. If you used version control, you should see all the changes made by code generation. I you didn't - you should start using it.

Comment: Thanks.  Was hoping for a more automatic way.  Like `ember destroy `

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe there to be no option to 'undo' from the [source code](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/tree/master/lib/mix/tasks) or the `mix help` command. This mix command `phoenix.gen.html` however does show what files were generated like below:

```
$ mix phoenix.gen.html Tweet tweets tweet:string

* creating web/controllers/tweet_controller.ex
* creating web/templates/tweet/edit.html.eex
* creating web/templates/tweet/form.html.eex
* creating web/templates/tweet/index.html.eex
* creating web/templates/tweet/new.html.eex
* creating web/templates/tweet/show.html.eex
* creating web/views/tweet_view.ex
* creating test/controllers/tweet_controller_test.exs
* creating priv/repo/migrations/20160118194027_create_tweet.exs
* creating web/models/tweet.ex
* creating test/models/tweet_test.exs
```

From this you know what files to delete.

Comment: By any luck, if you initiated your project using `git`, then it is more easy to revert using the git command `git clean -df`. This command will delete all your untracked files and directories. The generated files fall under untracked files. So, you can remove using that command. It only applies for `git` initiated projects or else you have to remove the files manually like mentioned above.

Comment: suppose that is ideal :-) especially since it is a good idea to commit before you run the generator. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is particularly good idea for a code generation tool to be able to undo any changes it did; this is just too complicated and error prone and version control systems are made for this purpose (tracking and managing changes).

So, to begin with, I strongly recommend using a version control system, like for example `git`. Before generating code using `mix phx.gen.html` or any other way, make sure you are have committed all your changes to the version control system. Then it is easy to rollback all the changes by restoring the work tree state from the repository (and maybe retry as many times until you have the right stuff generated). Even if new files are generated, using a version control system allows you to see what files were added to the work tree, so you do not need to copy the output from the `mix phx.gen.html` for possible later reference. A version control system also allows comparing the modified files to understand the changes made.

Comment: Why not? In Rails, for example, you can always run a a `destroy` task to delete everything that was created with `generate` task: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-destroy. Super handy :)

Comment: In my opinion, it is equally super handy to use version control for the same effect.